# Repository pattern - is a global repository a good idea?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, repository-pattern

I have the following interfaces in a WCF service:

- `IProductRepository`
- `IFieldRepository`
- `IFieldValueRepository`
- `ICategoryRepository`

I implement each of these in a separate project called `DatabaseRepository`, while `Product`, `Field`, `FieldValue` and `Category` all sit in a common library shared between the service and the repository project.

Products contain Fields, which in turn contain FieldValues.  I don't like the idea of my service constructor having 4 repositories passed in, so I also have `IGlobalRepository`, which contains a property for each other repository.  I instantiate my service by passing a concrete implementation of `IGlobalRepository` to the constructor, using Ninject conventions based binding to handle this for me when the service is hosted in IIS.

So on my web service `GetProductsByCategory` looks something like this:

```
private IGlobalRepository Repo { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByCategory(int CategoryID){
    return Repo.ProductRepository.GetByCategory(int CategoryID);
}
```

This is all well and good, except that products have fields, and fields have values.  Does that mean that I need to pass concrete implementations of `IFieldRepository` and `IFieldValueRepository` to `Repo.ProductRepository`?

I'm sure someone will suggest that `ProductRepository` should also be responsible for fetching field data, but I have it in a separate repository so that I can fetch fields independent of the product they are attached to.

Before I stared adopting the repository pattern, I would simply call a static method on Field or FieldValue in order to get what I needed.  Passing around repositories seems like a much less elegant way of working.

So now to my actual question:

Is a global repository a good idea?  I realise this is partly subjective, but would love to hear the opinions of others, and more importantly, what is considered best practice for this kind of scenario.

Comment: Are you writing unit tests in this project?

Comment: Yes I am.  It's actually an existing project that I am refactoring to use the repository pattern for that very purpose.

Comment: That `IGlobalRepository` really smells like a unit of work; nothing wrong with that.

Comment: What you're doing sounds like a lot of code in your WCF project and a lot of maintenance. You might want to consider using a design that requires less maintenance, such as [this design](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a global repository is a good idea.

You should create the repository definition according to usage. So yeah, the product repo should return all required data and it has nothing to do with the FieldRepo or other repo.

The app is coupled only to the interface and one repository can implement multiple interfaces. Also, you can have diferent concrete repositories working with the same db. The point of the repo is not to have one repo for each entity, it's to provide an interface for the app to get what it needs from the presistence. How you structure the things INSIDE persistence, that's a different story.

So, at least as an expriment try redefining the repo interfaces to return directly the objects the app needs it, ignoring which is entity, which object is part of another and so on.

Then start implementing the concrete repos. Remember, you have as many models as the app needs. Only in trivial cases there's one model to rule'm all